# Mapsforge Android library : onTouchEvent method in the ItemizedOverlay class

Tags: android, touch-event, mapsforge

I am using mapsforge library. I want to implement feature to move Overlay with finger. To implement this feature it is required to have `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)` method in the `ItemizedOverlay` class. 
But only methods I get are `onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView)` and `onLongPress(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView)` in `ItemizedOverlay` class.

Has anybody faced this problem of moving overlays with finger in **Mapsforge**? ...please help me

I tried another approach, I downloaded the source code using **git bash**. But surprisingly I could not find ItemizedOverlay class. Is this source not updated in downloads section?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is an existing method ? In my version of mapforge (0.3) ? I only have onTap() and onLongPressMethod() to manage user interactions.

Comment: @DavidN: Yes you are right. But in map v1 api you can get `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)` method, using this method I can move ItemizedOverlays. Is it possible to implment this method in **Mapsforge**?